# remove elements from nested object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to remove object based on conditional check from the JSON object using angularjs/jQuery. 
I tried with below code but output is not as expected.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/EWwbETITqn7G79Xypt0g?p=preview

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.responseData = {
    "data": [{
      "name": "Machine", "quantity": 20, "snVal": 22,
      "machine1": [{ "id": 2009, "machineName": "ASD1", "trackID": "34219", "status": "delivered" },
      { "id": 27893, "machineName": "PX20AA", "trackID": "3422", "status": "avail" }],
      "machine2": [{ "id": 1023, "machineName": "XY22", "trackID": "1345", "status": "avail" },
      { "id": 1233, "machineName": "PP3DF", "trackID": "112", "status": "delivered" }
      ]
    }]
  }
  console.log("R1 :: " + JSON.stringify($scope.responseData));
  $scope.newResponse = $.grep($scope.responseData.data, function (element, index) { return element.status == "delivered" }, true);
  console.log("R2 after removing elements:: " + JSON.stringify($scope.newResponse));
});
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What do you want to remove? Do you wanna filter objects with status delivered?

Comment: Yes, i want to remove the object with status delivered from $scope.responseData

Comment: in all the machines?

Comment: Yes in all the machines

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
let responseData = { "data": [{ "name": "Machine", "quantity": 20, "snVal": 22, "machine1": [{ "id": 2009, "machineName": "ASD1", "trackID": "34219", "status": "delivered" }, { "id": 27893, "machineName": "PX20AA", "trackID": "3422", "status": "avail" }], "machine2": [{ "id": 1023, "machineName": "XY22", "trackID": "1345", "status": "avail" }, { "id": 1233, "machineName": "PP3DF", "trackID": "112", "status": "delivered" }] }] } ;

let newResponse = responseData;
    newResponse.data.forEach(function (item) {
      for (j in item) {
        if (j.includes("machine")) {
      //better you check if type is array, using Object.prototype.toString.call(j) === "[object Array]"
          item[j] = item[j].reduce(function (acc, machine) {
            if (machine.status !== "delivered"){
              acc.push(machine);
            }
            return acc;
          }, []);
        }
      }
    })|
console.log(newResponse);
```

Here we are just iterating through all objects in the data field. Since properties like machine1, machine2 is an array, we iterate through it and filter all machines which are not delivered.

You must note that I have used a [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and array [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method here.